# How to use POST request data to find data with pymongo

Tags: python, post, flask

In the Flask app I'm working on, There is a `/login` route and I want to find user from mongodb according to the username,which is sent as a part of a POST request. However, for some reason, when I make a request to `http://localhost:5000/user/login` through POSTman, Flask server throws Timeout error. The below is what I have tried.

```
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,Blueprint
from database import db
from bson.json_util import dumps

user = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@user.route('/login',methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    user = db.user.find({'username': request.json['username']})
    return dumps(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you get that specific error. One word of caution, you are reusing the user variable inside and outside the function call. This example works:

In mongo:

```
db.user.insert({"username": "Buster"})
```

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['test']


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    user_records = db.user.find({'username': request.json['username']})
    return dumps(user_records)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Curl test:

```
curl.exe -X POST http://localhost:5000/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{\"username\": \"Buster\"}'
```

Result:

```
[{"_id": {"$oid": "5d6d07b012be0deafd736466"}, "username": "Buster"}]
```

Comment: Actually that error has happened because I forgot to start mongodb server :-D. Anyway, gonna accept your answer because it's correct..